# PDO nesting transactions causes PHP to hang

Tags: php, transactions

In PHP, using the built-in PDO database abstraction layer, it's not uncommon to have code like this:

```
function B()
{
    $db = new PDO(...);
    $db->beginTransaction();

    // do something

    $db->commit();
}

function A()
{
    $db = new PDO(...);
    $db->beginTransaction();

    // do something

    B();

    $db->commit();
}
```

Note that both A and B get their own database connection, and both start a transaction, and that **A calls B**. The result is, in some cases (namely, where B is doing something which *depends on something A did*), that this coding pattern will result in a deadlock.

For example, suppose we have tables `Foo` and `Bar`. `Foo` contains a foreign key referencing `Bar`, and is set to `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Let's say function `A` updates `Foo` to change the value of that foreign key field, and then function `B` deletes the now-unused record in `Bar`. Because `A`'s transaction hasn't committed, the SQL in `B` will wait for it, even though it will never be committed until `B` returns.
Is there a way to solve this problem without passing database objects to every function? It really seems like PDO itself should be able to deal with this properly, by simply keeping track of nested transactions.

I have tried the solution in the comments [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), where PDO is subclassed to do nested transaction counting, however it doesn't seem to actually work - I assume because the `$db` objects in `A()` and `B()` are not the same instance, so they are unaware of each other, and the value of the counter in either instance isn't correct.

Comment: "it's not uncommon"? Really?

Comment: Sure, why not? This seems to be the most obvious implementation. The [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) seem to do exactly this, for example - see "Example #2". What would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really only be using one instance of PDO. You need to figure out how to pass it around. There are many ways. Pass it directly, singletons, global functions. Pick a method and use it.

Comment: This seems to me like something the PDO connection pooling code ought to handle. And furthermore, I don't see anywhere in the documentation where it says that only once instance should exist at a time. Do you have some reference that this is the correct way to design things?

Answer (score 0):

If you really intend A() and B() to each be in their own transactions then this is unsolvable at any level. You've simply coded a guaranteed deadlock.

If you don't care whether B() is in its own transaction, as long as it is in **some** transaction, then you still have an impossible situation. B() can't be inside A()'s transaction because transactions don't span connections. But B() can't be in a separate transaction without causing the deadlock problem. Therefore, B() can't be in any transaction.

If you don't care whether B() is in a transaction at all, at least in this case, then you would need some kind of application-level introspection about transaction nesting. B() would have to check and obey this. But PDO can't do it unless you wrap it to include at least some singleton functionality. But I think you **do** want B() in a transaction. You just want it to be in A()'s transaction so that there's no deadlock.

In that case the only good solution is Damien's, though you'll still need to use one of those PDO wrappers that tracks nested transactions. That's the only way to have both your functions start transactions when called independently, but know that only the first will start a transaction when they are called in a nested fashion.